# Frobenius method. Problem finding a recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

The equation is $2z^2w''+3zw'-w=0$

$z_0=0$ is a regular singular point, so $w(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^{n+r}$

then $w'(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r)a_nz^{n+r-1}$ and $w''(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r)(n+r-1)a_nz^{n+r-2}$

Replacing in the equation:

$2z^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r)(n+r-1)a_nz^{n+r-2}+3z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+r)a_nz^{n+r-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^{n+r}=0$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nz^{n+r}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3(n+r)a_nz^{n+r}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^{n+r}=0$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [2(n+r)(n+r-1)a_nz^{n+r}+ 3(n+r)a_nz^{n+r}- a_nz^{n+r}]=0$

$2(n+r)(n+r-1)a_n+ 3(n+r)a_n- a_n=0$

$(2(n+r)(n+r-1)+3(n+r)-1) a_n=0$

At this point, how can I construct a recurrence relation since I only got $a_n$?, I'd need $a_{n+1}$, right?

I already found the indicial equation and its roots, which are $r_1=1/2$ and $r_2=-1$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last equation is all you get. There's no recurrence, and you don't need one.

You *necessarily* have $\color{blue}{a_n=0}$ for $n>0$. Otherwise, if $a_n\neq 0$ for some $n>0$, you would have both $r$ and $n+r$ be roots of $2r^2+r-1=0$ (the indical equation). In our case, this is clearly impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that, for this problem, Frobelius method is not required. Let $w(z)=z u(z)$ to end with
$$6u''+13u'=0$$ Just reduction of order and a quite simple problem.

Comment: $w'=zu'+u$, $w''=zu''+2u'$, $$0=2z^2w''+3zw'-w=[2z^3u''+4z^2u']+[3z^2u'+3zu]-zu=z(2z^2u''+7zu'+2u),$$ I do not see how that could work. What you can do is combine to $$0=2z(zw)''-(zw)',$$ which corresponds to the characteristic root $r=-1$.

Comment: It's $3zu$ not $2zu$ Lutz @LutzLehmann It fosent change that much.

Comment: $2z^2w''+3zw'-w=0 \implies (2z^2w')'-(wz)'=0$ works too. @LutzLehmann